# Find the index related to the widgets inside a layout PyQt

Tags: pyqt

I have a central widget(self.widget) and inside it a QHBoxLayout(self.box)

And I have placed three buttons inside this layout

What I want is to print the button index by clicking on each button

For example, when I click on button 3, the index of this button will be printed

But when I click on one of the buttons, none is returned for me

and index -1 is returned

Because the button becomes none, it naturally gets the wrong index

Note that I know that I can find the clicked button in other ways

But I want to find the clicked button using `self.widget.childAt(e.pos())`

Where is the problem?

code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

class CustomPushButton(QPushButton):
    signal = pyqtSignal(QEvent)
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.signal.emit(event)
        

class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.box)

        self.button = CustomPushButton('button1')
        self.button2 = CustomPushButton('button2')
        self.button3 = CustomPushButton('button3')

        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button3)


        self.button.signal.connect(self.findIndex)
        self.button2.signal.connect(self.findIndex)
        self.button3.signal.connect(self.findIndex)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.show()
        
    def findIndex(self,e):
        button = self.widget.childAt(e.pos())
        print(button)
        print('button',self.box.indexOf(button))


app = QApplication([])
m = main()
m.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each widget has it's own local coordinate system, and the `QMouseEvent.pos()` method returns a `QPoint` in that widgets local coordinate system.  However the `QWidget.childAt()` method expects the parameter to be in it's own coordinate system.

So when you send the event generated by the button and then apply its position to the parent widgets coordinate system, it is unlikely that the button will be found at those coordinates.

What you can do instead is map the coordinates to the buttons parent using the `mapToParent` method, prior to emitting the signal, and sending the `QPoint` result for the mapped position as the signal parameter.

For example:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

class CustomPushButton(QPushButton):
    signal = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.signal.emit(self.mapToParent(event.pos()))
        

class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.box)

        self.button = CustomPushButton('button1')
        self.button2 = CustomPushButton('button2')
        self.button3 = CustomPushButton('button3')

        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button3)


        self.button.signal.connect(self.findIndex)
        self.button2.signal.connect(self.findIndex)
        self.button3.signal.connect(self.findIndex)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        
    def findIndex(self,e):
        button = self.widget.childAt(e)
        print(button)
        print('button',self.box.indexOf(button))


app = QApplication([])
m = main()
m.show()
app.exec()
```

After applying the above changes, after pushing each button the terminal output looks like:

```
<__main__.CustomPushButton object at 0x000001FEFF4CA440>
button 0
<__main__.CustomPushButton object at 0x000001FEFF4CA4D0>
button 1
<__main__.CustomPushButton object at 0x000001FEFF4CA560>
button 2
```

P.S.  You are also calling `show()`  twice.  once inside the constructor and again in afterwards toward the bottom, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, now it works properly...
You are right about the show method and I was not paying attention and used it twice

Comment: Note that this considers only the case for which the *receiver* (the object that contains the function that is connected to the signal) is the **direct** parent of the widget. A more appropriate approach should use the [`globalPosition()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsinglepointevent.html#globalPosition) (aka, `globalPos()` for older Qt versions) of the event and remap that point using [`mapFromGlobal()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal-1).

Comment: @musicamante why is it more appropriate?  If you know the widget is the parent widget then why wouldn't mapToParent be the appropriate method?

Comment: @Alexander One of the main principles of OOP tells that an object (a class/instance or function) should provide the same expected behavior independently from the context given the same conditions. In other words, objects not strictly related to others (by their nature or purpose) should always provide the same result to any other object within the object tree. Imagine a slightly more complex situation where `CustomPushButton` is actually used within a *further* parent (for instance, a QGroupBox or a QFrame) that is actually a child of `widget`: in that case, the result would be unreliable.

Comment: @Alexander And that's because `mapToParent()` always maps the point to the *closest* parent of the widget, which has a different origin point for its coordinate system than that of its "main" parent. A common coordinate system is required though, and that's why `globalPosition()` is more appropriate, because it will always return the absolute coordinates of the mouse cursor, which then can be mapped to any parent in the widget tree and provide correct results indeed, no matter their relation (as long as they are within the same object branches, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation *warns* about doing it for strictly OOP related aspects, as long as the object structure is contained and known, you can use [`QObject.sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#sender):

```py
    def findIndex(self,e):
        button = self.sender()
        ...
```

In that way you don't even need to send the event within the signal, which is not forbidden, but conceptually and potentially dangerous, and normally discouraged as such.

An even more simpler approach would be to let the signal emit the instance itself:

```py
class CustomPushButton(QPushButton):
    signal = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.signal.emit(self)


class main(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def findIndex(self, button):
        print('button', self.box.indexOf(button))
```

This may not look completely elegant, and it could be an issue in some very special, fringe cases (threading, multiprocessing), but it's fine enough for simpler situations like these, in which we can assume that the object is still existing when the signal is received.

Note that the `object` argument of the signal is to simplify some aspects related to the Python/C++ layering of the binding. If you *do* know what you're doing, you can use `QWidget` or `QPushButton` instead.